# Get elements that are not inside of an element that has a known class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose you have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="class1">
        <input type="text" data-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <input type="text" data-required="true"/>
</div>
```

I want to get all elements that have `data-required` attribute from `.test` that are not inside of the `.class1` div.
So, in the example above only the second input would be returned.

I tried:

`$(".test [data-required]:not('.class1')")`

but it returns the both input because `:not` doesn't select the parent elements.

Is this possible with one jQuery selector?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wERTv/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing this:

```
$(".test [data-required]").filter(function() {
   return !$(this).closest('.class1').length;
}).css("background", "red");
```

`.filter()` method is much faster than spaghetti-like selectors, if you don't want to use `.filter()`, probably you can use this long, inefficient selector:

```
$(".test > [data-required], .test :not(.class1) [data-required]");
```

Comment: Ok, I will not use *spaghetti-like selectors* if they are slow. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use `filter()`:

```
var $inputs = $('.test [data-required]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.class1').length == 0;
});
```

Comment: I would not use `filter()` if I could... Cannot be this done with just a selector?

Comment: I'm afraid not, selectors cannot go up the DOM tree, only down. What's the problem with `filter()` anyway? I think it's one of the most helpful jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

If the input you want to find is always a direct child of `.test` div, you can use

```
$(".test > [data-required]").css("background", "red");
```

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/wERTv/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below. It selects only the direct children of `.test`.

**Note:** Wouldn't include elements with `data-required` under say `.class2` also.

```
$(".test > [data-required]").css("background", "red");
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/wERTv/2/)

**EDIT:** Updated based on your further clarifications.

```
$(".test [data-required]").each(function() {
   if (!$(this).parents('.class1').length)
       $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

[Working Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/wERTv/3/)